# How to adjust probability of opponent having a specific card in a set in Clue?

Tags: probability, games

I am developing a computer version of the game [Cluedo/Clue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluedo) (the mystery game) and for the AI I need to track the probability of a opponent having a specific card. This includes making deductions from other players' questions. Thus each person will obviously have a previously calculated chance of having each card. 16.66667% per card starting for 18 unknown cards and 3 cards per person. Now if another player makes a guess and someone proves them wrong how does this probability change for the 3 cards used in the guess and of course the other cards? All the information you gain is the 3 cards guessed and that one or more of the 3 cards guessed are in the player's hand. The goal of course is to try to get close to 100% probability on 3 cards and 0% on the rest.

How would this be done?

Essentially the player could have 18 possible cards. The probability of a player having that card is adjusted as the game goes on. For instance if the card is revealed to you you know 100% that that player has that card. But if another player makes an injury the revealing player is only required to show the player who made the enquiry. Thus only confirming to other players that one of the three cards suggested is in his hand.

Thus given a set of 18 discrete probabilities with an unknown distribution. How would the distribution be updated given a 100% chance of One in a subset of three being the right card. There are 3 right cards.

Comment: As it stands this question isn't quite self-contained as it requires knowledge of the rules of Clue/Cluedo to do so. I think the game is probably well-known enough that the question shouldn't be closed as unclear, but it may help you get answers if you could include a few sentences to summarise the rules.

Comment: Also, it'd be worth mentioning what use you are making of information revealed over the course of the game - are you working entirely from other players' questions? (One might draw some limited inferences, for instance, from the fact that a player passes up the opportunity to enter a particular room and prefers to walk straight past it, apparently towards another room. I take it this kind of activity will be ignored by the game AI, and similarly that the AI will assume human players are raising questions based purely on the cards.)

Comment: No the AI will make use of this information. As the player is required to reveal a card if he is passes all cards in the set are set to 0% and the probably redistributed.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer - that's what I mean, that the AI isn't trying to second-guess anybody, but is only working off information directly revealed by the questions.

Comment: Yes the AI is trying to determine the hand of each player taking information from various actions the hard one to calculate being another player asking a question to another player and thus getting more information about the second players hand (not the hand of the player asking but only the one answering)